# O que é boilerplate code?

Tags: java, boilerplate

Tenho percebido o uso frequente do termo em alguns fóruns e fiquei me perguntando qual o seu significado e de onde surgiu tal expressão.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

"Boilerplate" é um termo muito utilizado para se referir a trechos de documentos (por exemplo jurídicos) que são sempre os mesmos, de documento pra documento, de modo que não acrescentam muita coisa mas mesmo assim não podem ser omitidos. Você já deve ter visto em licenças de software, por exemplo, a parte que diz que "NÃO HÁ NENHUMA GARANTIA PARA O PROGRAMA, NO LIMITE PERMITIDO PELA LEI APLICÁVEL. EXCETO QUANDO..." etc. Todo mundo já conhece, ninguém nem lê porque já sabe de cor o que está escrito, mas o documento não estaria completo sem ela.

Quando se aplica esse termo ao código, pode ter um sentido "inocente" (como mostrado na [resposta do @AndersonBS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10576/215), se referindo a um padrão pronto, um esqueleto, a partir do qual você faz o resto), mas também um sentido pejorativo: é aquele código que você precisa escrever toda vez - porque a sintaxe da linguagem exige - mas que também não acrescenta muita coisa, já que é igual em todo programa. Em geral, quando se diz que uma linguagem ou plataforma tem muito boilerplate se está dizendo que ela é **pouco expressiva** ("fala muito pra dizer pouco").

Como exemplo, veja o programa "hello world" em Python:

```python
print("Olá, Mundo!")
```

O mesmo programa em Java:

```java
public class OlaMundo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Olá, Mundo!");
    }
}
```

E o mesmo programa em C#:

```cs
using System;

namespace Teste
{
    class OlaMundo
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Olá, Mundo!");
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>[Fonte: Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa_Ol%C3%A1_Mundo#Java)</sub>

Em todos os três casos há apenas uma "linha útil": aquela que imprime a string na saída. Todo o resto é boilerplate. Código que você vai ter que escrever de novo e de novo e de novo toda vez que for criar um programa. Mesmo que seu IDE (ambiente de desenvolvimento) crie o esqueleto pra você, ainda é um trecho inútil que está lá ocupando espaço, tomando tempo da compilação e distraindo sua atenção do que o código faz de útil.

Nota: a presença de *algum* boilerplate não torna a linguagem automaticamente ruim; ela só é um **indício** de que provavelmente essa linguagem te obriga a escrever mais do que o necessário para executar a mesma função, comparado a outras com menos boilerplate.

Comment: Muito boa explicação!! Obrigado

Comment: É quase uma sacanagem dar tanto espaço assim em C# para parecer que ele gera código enorme :D E hoje C# permite fazer o mesmo com apenas uma linha, e curta.

Answer (score 29):

O termo deriva da fabricação de aço, onde boilerplate é o aço laminado em grandes placas para uso em caldeiras a vapor.

Em tecnologia da informação, "boilerplate code" é um trecho de código que pode ser reutilizado várias vezes sem nenhuma ou com poucas alteração em sua consistência. Presume-se que esse trecho de código já foi testado inúmeras vezes e é tão consistente quanto o aço.

Answer (score -1):

Em inglês a expressão boilerplate significa um template, ou seja, uma forma padrão de se escrever algo que pode ser copiado, usado, principalmente, em contratos e documentos legais.
Quem lida com aquecedores e caldeiras (boilers) sabe que esses equipamento possuem riscos operacionais e limites bem estritos de funcionamento. Também há legislação específica para seu uso e, uma das regras mais importantes e que deve ser fixada no equipamento uma placa (plate) contendo dados importantes de seu funcionamento, como temperatura e pressão máxima de operação, tipo de combustível usado, volume, etc... Essa placa tem que conter um  mínimo de informação e estar escrita de uma determinada forma. Mas quase ninguém lê essas informações.