# É desrecomendado utilizar scaffolding?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Certos frameworks oferecem a possibilidade de [scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)), ou seja, informa-se alguns parâmetros (como o nome do modelo/tabela e atributos/colunas) e o framework gera todo (ou boa parte) o código necessário para aquele formulário funcionar inicialmente, incluindo a migração do banco de dados (e às vezes até os testes unitários!).

É claro que não dá pra criar uma aplicação séria utilizando ***apenas*** scaffolding, na prática você sempre terá que alterar o código gerado de acordo com suas necessidades. Mas ainda assim isto poupa um belo tempo!

Porém, alguns recomendam scaffolding apenas para testes, protótipos, etc., mas ***nunca*** para aplicações que irão para produção. Isso é correto? Há ou não problemas de usar scaffolding neste caso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende da qualidade do *scaffolding*, e de quão bem ele lida com as inevitáveis **mudanças** que surgirão no decorrer do projeto.

De um modo geral, toda vez que um sistema (ex.: sua aplicação) precisa interagir/integrar com outro sistema (ex.: o banco de dados) é necessário um mapeamento de conceitos, pois não só cada um lida com uma abstração diferente (ex.: objetos vs. tabelas) como é necessário estabelecer qual entidade de um lado corresponde a uma entidade do outro (ex.: a classe X representa a tabela Y). Isso às vezes é apelidado [*glue code*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_code) ("código cola").

Há várias maneiras de se fazer isso (*hardcoding*, arquivos de configuração, introspecção/reflexão, etc), sendo o *scaffolding* uma delas. A ideia por trás dessa técnica é - assumindo que bastante [código *boilerplate*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10575/215) precisa ser escrito - facilitar a tarefa combinando um código menor, mais declarativo, com dados obtidos via introspecção, produzindo a partir dos mesmos um código completo. Isso é diferente de, por exemplo, gerar um "esqueleto" (*skeleton*) a partir dos dados e deixar o programador completá-lo (comum em ferramentas de UML, por exemplo - pelo menos as mais antigas).

Pessoalmente, não me agrada a ideia (pelo menos do ["*scaffolding* durante o design"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29#Run_time_vs_Design_time_Scaffolding)) porque contesto o pressuposto de que esse código *boilerplate* é necessário - creio que os mesmos resultados poderiam ser obtidos com código genérico, via reflexão. Mas em si, a prática não me parece detrimental em nenhum sentido (talvez exceto pelas pilhas de código gerado...). Não vejo porque seria adequada pra protótipos mas não pra produção.

Quanto a problemas em se usar essa técnica, só vejo o potencial de surgirem problemas à medida que o projeto evolui. Digamos que foi feito o *scaffolding*, e percebeu-se que algumas alterações eram necessárias no código gerado. As mesmas foram feitas, e no futuro houve a necessidade de se evoluir o esquema (i.e. fazer mudanças no BD). O que fazer com o código já existente? Normalmente, a resposta seria "gerá-lo de novo", mas como foram feitas alterações no mesmo, teria-se que fazê-las todas de novo. Alternativamente, pode-se não refazer o *scaffolding*, fazendo as mudanças todas à mão, mas o volume dessas mudanças pode ser significativo (e fazê-las à mão traz potencial para erros).

É nesse ponto que a ideia me incomoda: se um sistema é construído sob a filosofia do *scaffolding*, ele não hesitará em adicionar mais e mais código ao seu processo de geração, partindo do princípio que isso não traz problemas ao programador. Quando na verdade isso traz sim problemas, como já mencionado. Já um sistema que use uma filosofia alternativa, nem que seja a de "*hardcode* tudo", terá sempre em mente o **custo** das alterações ao programador, e tentará minimizar esse custo da forma que for possível (através de código genérico, introspecção/reflexão, ou simplesmente via ferramentas auxiliares para modificar as configurações).

Não tenho experiência com o Rails pra dizer se a qualidade do seu *scaffolding* é ou não boa. De modo que minha recomendação é observar os seguintes parâmetros ao decidir por usar ou não essa funcionalidade: 1) se eu precisar refazer o *scaffolding*, vou perder alguma coisa? e 2) se meu banco precisar mudar, radicalmente até, quanto código eu terei que escrever à mão para adequar meu sistema atual às mudanças? Simule alguns cenários assim, veja o que o Rails te oferece pra te ajudar nisso, e assim avalie se é algo factível de se fazer em produção ou não (onde não dá pra "jogar tudo fora e começar de novo", mas se precisa dar manutenção seja isso difícil ou não).

Comment: Boa resposta! [Esta resposta](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/75222/142751) no Programmers deve te dar uma ideia do uso de scaffolding em Rails. A seguinte frase acho interessante: *"Eu* ***utilizo*** *o scaffolding, mas* ***não confio*** *nele"*. Na verdade, no Rails, o scaffolding não é tão "profundo" assim. Ele te gera todo o esqueleto (migration, modelo, controlador, as ações CRUD e HTML básico), mas é inevitável adicionar/remover/alterar coisas aqui e ali. Acho pouco provável que alguém vá gerá-lo pela segunda vez: é bem mais fácil alterar o existente do que começar tudo do zero.

Comment: @Andrey É, eu me lembrava mais ou menos disto mesmo (fiz uns tutoriais de Rails muitos anos atrás, antes de decidir que não me interessava por essa plataforma), mas como sua pergunta era sobre *scaffolding* em geral - e não especificamente sobre *scaffolding* no Rails - quis dar uma resposta também geral. A ideia em si não é de todo ruim, mas sou bastante cético quanto às possibilidades reais de se aplicá-la na prática sem incorrer nos problemas citados na minha resposta.

Answer (score 6):

> Se a única ferramenta que você tem é um martelo, todos os problemas parecem pregos.

<sup>*Abraham Maslow*</sup>

---

*Scaffolding* é apenas uma ferramenta - útil em alguns casos e desnecessária em outros.

Porém, ao dizer que uma solução que utilize esta prática não pode ir para produção, detratores estão sofrendo do mal inverso ao mencionado por Maslow. Eu considero um purismo desnecessário.

Tabelas-satélite (Categorias, Estados ou Tipos, por exemplo) seriam beneficiárias claras de scaffolding sem muita necessidade de *refactoring*.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sou contra geradores de código, mas provavelmente você irá duplicar lógica em várias situações, há outras maneiras de você agilizar seu processo de CRUD, utilizando OO com padrões como Observer, DI e outros. Hoje eu utilizo geradores de HTML e Migração de banco nada mais. Para quem utiliza PHP e Symfony2 o [SyliusResourceBundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/index.html) é um pacote que elimina os geradores de código e eu recomendo =). E para quem não é do PHP e Symfony2 recomendo a leitura e entender a ideia dele, pois pode ser aplicada em outros projetos.

Answer (score -1):

*Pergunta antiga, mas gostaria de acrescentar opiniões em 2019.*

Hoje diversos frameworks permitem você configurar e customizar seus templates de scanffolding, ex: `ASP.NET`

Você pode personalizar tudo, desde o front end para estar de acordo com seu projeto (*Layout*) até configurações mais complexas,

**Ex:** Como meus softwares utilizam soft-delete *(não deleta realmente, apenas marca como deletado)* Toda a função de delete é modificada para essa nova versão, além das injeções de dependências que necessito e já são configurados para quando ele crie a controller *(Projeto MVC)* já tenha as dependências, construtores necessários, então perco algum tempo configurando o scanffolding, mas depois é só alegria.

Comment: Não entendi o pq do -1, caso possível colocar nos comentários assim posso melhorar