# Qual a definição de código verboso? E por que é interessante reduzi-lo?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, estilo-de-codificação, ecmascript-6

Recentemente tenho ouvido falar à respeito de redução de código verboso (junto ao termo *boiler plate code*), e também ao estudar ES6 ao cair nas *arrow-functions*. Gostaria de uma definição mais clara à respeito do que seria código verboso? E por que é interessante reduzi-lo?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é boilerplate code?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10575/91)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Código verboso é aquele que precisa de mais palavras, ou palavras mais longas, do que o necessário para expressar adequadamente a intenção do código.

Em códigos verbosos existem muitos símbolos ou símbolos muito longos.

Há uma corrente que diz que se o código for mais próximo possível da linguagem natural para o humano mais ele será legível. Se isso fosse verdade as linguagens hoje tenderiam a isso cada vez mais e COBOL ainda faria muito sucesso para novos projetos.

Há outra corrente que diz que o código é mais legível se ele for mais curto, se você conseguir colocar mais código compreensível no mesmo campo de visão. Não tenho como localizar, mas há estudos que indicam isso, e vale para qualquer coisa, não só programação.

Deveria ser óbvio que se você tiver distrações ao longo do código, se tiver informação demais, ou se o código ficar mnemônico (cifrado) demais por tentar encurtar tanto quanto dá, ele não fica legível. Tem que ter o compromisso certo que dê a mais adequada expressividade ao que quer que faça.

Em alguns casos escrever demais pode até passar a impressão inicial de ambiguidade. Há casos que incentiva escrever um código de um jeito quando ali caberia um outro estilo.

Linguagens de programação deveriam sempre incentivar a escrita do código mais curta possível que seja facilmente compreensível, especialmente em situações onde conceitos acabam se misturando.

## Exemplo da pergunta

Por que escrever `function() { return 42; }` quando pode escrever apenas `() => 42`?

Isso é especialmente útil em casos que a função é passada como argumento de outra função. Fica confuso ter uma função dentro de um argumento, fica longo demais para ler e não há ganho.

Usamos convenções para indicar de forma mais compacta e possivelmente concisa a mesma coisa. Assim eliminamos: a palavra `function` que neste contexto não é necessária; e o `return` porque a ideia é que essa forma seja muito simples, que apenas tenha uma linha e já seja um retorno sempre, e que por ter só uma linha, não precisa do `;`, e também as chaves não são necessárias pelo mesmo motivo. Mas adicionamos `=>` para tornar não ambíguo e mostrar que a intenção é essa.

## Código curto

Não confundir código conciso (não verboso) com código mais curto possível. Não vai abusar de variáveis de uma letra, de juntar tudo em uma linha só, cortar espaços, etc. só para parecer mais curto, isso é cortar a carne e não a gordura do código. O ideal é escrever código terso, ou seja, limpo. Se amontoar tudo, ele não fica limpo.

Entende-se que uma notação matemática é tão expressiva quanto uma notação em língua natural se for para expressar um conceito que será bastante usado, e por ser mais curta, sucinta, que vai direto ao ponto, fica mais fácil ler. Claro que primeiro a pessoa tem que aprender aquela notação, mas essa é a parte fácil de aprender programar.

O que não dá certo é obrigar o programador ter que aprender uma notação nova a cada base de código que ele vá mexer. Em cada linguagem dá. Inclusive a maioria copia das outras, então é raro alguém inventar algo muito novo, e em geral traz o que já se usa na matemática.

Código menos verboso deve ficar sempre mais claro e legível, não o contrário.

Exemplo para ver como é mais fácil ler:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var quadrados = array.map(x => x * x);
var quadrados2 = array.map(function(x) { return x * x });
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Map.js).

Claro [que quem não conhece a notação da primeira pode não entender, mas é uma deficiência temporária dela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101), aprendeu, fica mais fácil ler o código terso.

## Linguagens verbosas

Algumas linguagens são mais verbosas que outras. Elas preferem palavras do que símbolos. Preferem ser mais explícito do que implícito (e tem caso que é melhor mesmo). Preferem nomes comumente usados que são longos porque soa mais natural. Algumas adotam um estilo ou paradigma que prega mais cerimônia e exige coisas que são pouco úteis na maioria dos casos para beneficiar os raros casos.

JavaScript nunca foi muito verbosa, mas foi um pouco, agora está se modernizando para ser menos ainda. [CoffeeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) é uma linguagem que roda em cima de JS que tem como característica principal ser bem pouco verbosa. Alguns acham que de forma exagerada. Quando exagera começa dar margem para erros ou ilegibilidade. Tem coisa que parece exagerada, mas tem uma função estar ali.

Comment: COBOL ainda é muito bem sucedido para novos projetos. Eu não tenho certeza qual é o seu ponto. Você acha que com a chegada do PC, com 95% + de programadores profissionais escrevendo em COBOL, a razão pela qual COBOL não é importante para as línguas modernas é ... algum mal definido "verbose"? Nada a ver com um compilador COBOL no momento ser sobre o mesmo custo que o PC? Sério?

Comment: Não sei do que está falando. praticamente só há projetos novos em COBOL que se associam a projetos antigos em COBOL ou em cenários muito específicos. COBOL foi minha segunda linguagem, mas 95% dos programadores de hoje nunca ouviram falar em COBOL. Não sei se tentou contestar que COBOL não é verboso, se foi isso, nem sei o que dizer, porque acho que é consenso que é a linguagem mais verbosa que existe.

Comment: A questão é Javascript e ES6. Ele menciona a palavra "verbose", então você menciona COBOL ... Você então liga "verbose" para por que há tão poucas pessoas (relativas) que sabem COBOL para não-COBOL ... para todos os programadores COBOL eu sei que comprou PCs de meados dos anos 80 para meados dos anos 90, o custo de um compilador era por que eles não escreveram em COBOL.

Comment: COBOL passou de ser a língua predominante de negócios, para não. Além de compiladores caros, quebrar os princípios da "ciência da computação" de acordo com aqueles que inventaram a ciência da computação provavelmente contribuiu para menos ensino. Há provavelmente multi-bilhões de máquinas X86 e menos de 10.000 "COBOL-domínio", mas o peso das transações entre grandes organizações é a outra maneira.

Comment: Eu negar COBOL é "verbose" nos termos da pergunta? Claro.

Answer (score 10):

A expressão "código verboso" refere-se a código que está mais longo do que seria expectável, seja porque a lógica está demasiado complicada, seja porque a própria linguagem assim o requer.

Por exemplo, neste caso os dois códigos fazem exatamente o mesmo, mas o segundo exemplo é muito menos "verboso" e fácil de compreender:

Java:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Ruby:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

Tipicamente quanto menos verboso, mais fácil/rápido é de compreender o código (embora não seja regra).

Mais informação sobre linguagens "verbosas":
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/why-is-verbosity-bad-for-a-programming-language

Answer (score 0):

A expressão código verboso esta relacionada com um código que usa muitas linhas para fazer algo que pode ser feito em menos sem comprometer a legibilidade.

Precisa haver uma harmonia entre a quantidade de linhas e a dificuldade de entendimento do comportamento esperado.

Em JS, mais especificadamente ES6 as arrow functions conseguem reduzir o número de linhas e manter o código legível.

```
// sem arrow function
let relatorio = {
  gerarPdf: function() {
    // código aqui...
  },
  gerarRelatorio: function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      this.gerarPdf();
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

// com arrow function
let relatorio = {
  gerarPdf: function() {
    // codigo aqui ...
  },
  gerarRelatorio: function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
    this.gerarPdf());
  }
}
```

O exemplo foi mínimo, mas da para ter ideia da melhoria de legibilidade e ainda com redução de linhas