# O que é codificação elegante?

Tags: terminologia, estilo-de-codificação

Sempre vejo algumas respostas de perguntas sugerindo que se fizer algo de forma x é mais elegante que a forma y. Comecei pensar o que seria elegante no nosso contexto.

9 páginas de 50 registros com o termo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=elegante

**Dicionário:**

> 1. que se caracteriza pela harmonia, leveza ou naturalidade.
>      "traje e."
>      2.
>      frequentado por pessoas elegantes (diz-se de lugar ou ambiente); seleto.
>      3.
>      requintado na escolha das palavras; apurado, fino.
>      "sintaxe e."
>      4.
>      moral ou intelectualmente correto; honrado, nobre.
>      "disputa e."
>      5.
>      relativo às pessoas elegantes ou a seus atos.
>      "jantar e."
>      6.
>      adjetivo e substantivo de dois gêneros
>      que ou quem revela bom gosto na escolha de suas vestes e no modo de usá-las.
>      "homem e."
>      7.
>      adjetivo e substantivo de dois gêneros
>      que ou quem revela correção e fineza nas atitudes; distinto, delicado.

Quando este termo começou ser utilizado em programação? Em programação o que pode-se definir como elegante?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [O que define um código limpo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/3635) - obs: desde que explicado que não é algo padronizado ou técnico ou qualquer coisa assim, a pergunta me parece valida se a(s) resposta(s) forem bem explicadas acho, o problema são as respostas ruins que costumam atrair, mas nem por isso deve deixar de perguntar.

Comment: Apesar de ser uma excelente pergunta, acho que pede respostas baseadas no achismo. Coisa que, se não me engano, é contra as diretrizes do stackoverflow. Correto ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Primeiro entenda que a avaliação sempre será subjetiva, ainda que possa haver critérios objetivos.

A definição do dicionário é boa. Claro que não ajuda entender os pontos a considerar, mas também acredito que nem em um livro dá para definir de forma concreta. E existem vários que tentam fazer isso.

- Obviamente que todo código elegante é correto, isso eu coloco como *hors concours*. Não basta "funcionar", tem que ser **correto**. Ele faz o que deveria fazer em qualquer situação planejada e lida bem com as situações não planejadas.
- Acho que a principal característica é [o código ser **legível** por profissionais qualificados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101). Note a diferenciação. Ser legível para leigos, estudantes, amadores os pseudo-profissionais não é um requisito para ser elegante. O código deve ser facilmente percebido, ainda que eventualmente precise de [comentário que façam sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101).
- Outra característica muito forte é que ele deve ser [simples, estúpido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). O problema pode ser [complexo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_complexity), a solução deve ser **simples**, que é o oposto de complicado.
- Ser um [código **limpo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/101) é outra característica. [Não deve ter nada que não precise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173190/101). Não deve ter mais de uma responsabilidade. Mas também não deve encurtar ao ponto de não ser fácil entender o que está ocorrendo ali. De nada adianta criar um monte de camadas para atingir este objetivo e piorar outro.
- O código deve ser **claro** e expressar bem o que deseja. Deve ser uma solução óbvia. Deve ser tão conciso quanto possível sem comprometer a legibilidade. Para isso deve ter as abstrações certas, e o nível abstrativo adequado.
- Geralmente ele deve fazer da forma como já é **conhecida** por todos e não tentar inventar uma forma esquisita sem necessidade. Deve escolher os algoritmos adequados. Não reinventar a roda, no bom sentido.
- Deve seguir **convenções** de codificação estabelecidas em termos gerais, pela linguagem e pela equipe. Assim fica mais fácil acompanhar o que está escrito. Código elegante está bem formatado, não tem brancos demais e nem de menos (vertical ou horizontal). Não tem abreviaturas desnecessárias, usa nomes significativos.
- Deve ter uma forma que **facilite a manutenção e evite *bugs***. Você pode confiar no código. Pode mudar sem susto?
- Provavelmente ele **não deve fazer [otimização prematura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101)**. Mas ele deve ser tão rápido quanto possível sem comprometer outras características. E é claro que deve ter a performance desejada, se possível. Mas mais que ser rápido, ele precisa ser eficiente.
- **Não deve ser *clever***. Essa é uma palavra geralmente usada para indicar que o programador tentou fazer um código muito inteligente, performático, curto, que parece fazer algo curioso, que se aproveita de alguma característica da linguagem ou da matemática para obter o resultado, mas que não é facilmente compreensível. *Clever code* pode parecer elegante, mas é o oposto.

Você só obtém isso se domina a computação (no sentido matemático e técnico), sabe como o computador, a linguagem e outros recursos funcionam.

Só pode fazer código elegante se entende o problema que está resolvendo e fez um planejamento prévio do que precisa, do que pode dar errado, de todas necessidades.

Então dá para dizer que só escreve código elegante sempre, quem tem experiência, e não é teimoso :) Claro que copiar código elegante de outros faz aquele trecho elegante, mas pra produzir código inovador elegante precisa "chão".

Elegância é fazer o que é mais adequado para aquele caso. E seguir regras prontas cegamente não ajuda muito. Por isso boas práticas não ajudam diretamente a fazer código elegante. São coisas distintas.

O código elegante é, possivelmente, aquele que alguém te mostra como você poderia ter feito e você fala "por que eu não pensei nisso antes?" :).

Um código [WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) não é elegante.

Tem linguagens que incentivam código elegante, outras nem tanto.

Ficou mais claro? Talvez não, mas é o tipo de coisa que não se mostra no papel. Como o nome indica, envolve (bom) gosto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ficou bem mais claro. Quando perguntei pensei que talvez seria difícil de explicar, mas creio que entendi a "essência".

Answer (score 3):

Excelente pergunta.

Embora isto possa trazer várias interpretações baseado na experiência profissional de cada desenvolvedor, o destino final de um código elegante deve atender alguns requisitos que, no final das contas, leva-nos a um código que atenderá a exigências de qualidade para alguém com vários anos de experiência na linguagem.

Listei alguns pontos abaixo, onde alguns deles podem ser entendidos como consequência natural dos outros, mas é importante listar todos:

- O código é **direto** e **objetivo** no seu propósito, não fazendo nada além de sua responsabilidade.
- O código **evita "super engenharias"** desnecessárias para o tamanho do problema que está disposto a resolver, com base nas informações disponíveis no momento.
- Classes, métodos e variáveis tem **nomes bem definidos**, fazendo exatamente o que espera-se deles ao ler o código.
- **Não viola aspectos das boas práticas** da linguagem e **não contém vulnerabilidades** óbvias.
- A solução aproxima-se do **mínimo possível de código** utilizado, não sendo tão curta a ponto de ficar indecifrável e não tão longa a ponto de desviar a atenção do entendimento.
- O código é **facilmente testável** por testes automatizados.
- **Não viola outros pontos importantes não-funcionais**, como segurança e desempenho, cumprindo o primeiro e sendo (ao menos) aceitável no segundo.
- Os comentários para descrever o que o código faz são ausentes, pois o código já é claro o suficiente. **Comentários** são encontrados apenas **para esclarecer dúvidas de negócio**.
- Se o **código** é contestado, o autor consegue facilmente defendê-lo, pois foi ele **tem base em diferentes fontes** para esclarecer sua qualidade, como: bons livros, autores, Internet (Stack Overflow, por exemplo) e ferramentas da área. Isto é importante, pois o entendimento de um código elegante pode divergir muito entre os desenvolvedores e uma "comprovação" pode ser necessária para consenso.