# Como faço para remover uma banda pelo o seu nome?

Tags: java, swing

Não estou conseguindo buscar as bandas dentro do arraylist. Para isso, fiz a leitura do arquivo.txt onde as informações(nome,país,nrointegrantes) são armazenadas. Fiz um split para acessar o nome, porém quando tento remover uma das bandas pelo o nome eu não estou conseguindo.

Acredito que o caminho seja algo parecido com isso mas não estou tendo sucesso.

As bandas são exibidas dentro de um textarea(taSaida) e informo a banda que desejo remover dentro do tfNomeBandaRemover.

Vou postar todo o código aqui abaixo:

Arquivo bandas.txt

```
Rush,Canada,3
The Who,Inglaterra,4
The Beatles,Inglaterra,4
Guns,Eua,5
```

Classe Banda

```
public class Banda {

    //Atributos
    private String nome;
    private String pais;
    private int nroIntegrantes;

    //construtor
    public Banda(String nome, String pais, int nroIntegrantes) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.pais = pais;
        this.nroIntegrantes = nroIntegrantes;
    }

    //GET e SET
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public int getNroIntegrantes() {
        return nroIntegrantes;
    }

    public void setNroIntegrantes(int nroIntegrantes) {
        this.nroIntegrantes = nroIntegrantes;
    }





}
```

Classe principal

```
public class Exercicio1 {

    private JFrame frmBandas;
    ArrayList<Banda> bandas = new ArrayList<Banda>();
    private JTextField tfPaisBanda;
    private JTextField tfNomeBanda;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTextField tfNroIntegrantes;
    private JTextField tfNomeBandaRemover;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JPanel panel4;
    private JTextArea taSaida;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Exercicio1 window = new Exercicio1();
                    window.frmBandas.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Exercicio1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmBandas = new JFrame();
        frmBandas.setTitle("BANDAS");
        frmBandas.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmBandas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmBandas.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel principal = new JPanel();
        frmBandas.getContentPane().add(principal);
        principal.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        principal.add(panel1, "name_47122994121324");
        panel1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCadastroDeBandas = new JLabel("MENU BANDAS");
        lblCadastroDeBandas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblCadastroDeBandas.setBounds(134, 27, 163, 22);
        panel1.add(lblCadastroDeBandas);

        JButton btnCadastrarBanda = new JButton("Cadastrar Banda");
        btnCadastrarBanda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //código MENU -> Cadastrar Banda

                panel1.setVisible(false);
                panel2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnCadastrarBanda.setBounds(138, 78, 137, 23);
        panel1.add(btnCadastrarBanda);

        JButton btnRemoverBanda = new JButton("Remover Banda");
        btnRemoverBanda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Código MENU -> Remover Banda
                panel1.setVisible(false);
                panel3.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnRemoverBanda.setBounds(138, 112, 137, 23);
        panel1.add(btnRemoverBanda);

        JButton btnConsultarBandas = new JButton("Consultar Bandas");
        btnConsultarBandas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Código MENU -> Consultar Bandas
                panel1.setVisible(false);
                panel4.setVisible(true);
                taSaida.setText("");  //ASSIM só exibe o arquivo TXT uma única vez

                // LEITURA TXT

                try {

                    FileReader ler = new FileReader("Pasta/bandas.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ler);

                    String nomeB = null;
                    String[] x;

                    while ((nomeB = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        x = nomeB.split(",");

                        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                            String paisB = (x[1]);

                            int nroIntegrantesb = Integer.parseInt(x[2]);   

                            //Objeto
                            bandas.add(new Banda(nomeB, paisB, nroIntegrantesb));
                        }

                        taSaida.append(nomeB + "\n");

                    }


                    //fechar
                    br.close();
                    ler.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }

        });
        btnConsultarBandas.setBounds(138, 146, 137, 23);
        panel1.add(btnConsultarBandas);

        JButton btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
        btnSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //SAIR
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnSair.setBounds(138, 180, 137, 23);
        panel1.add(btnSair);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        principal.add(panel2, "name_47123033318588");
        panel2.setLayout(null);

        tfPaisBanda = new JTextField();
        tfPaisBanda.setColumns(10);
        tfPaisBanda.setBounds(219, 123, 128, 20);
        panel2.add(tfPaisBanda);

        tfNomeBanda = new JTextField();
        tfNomeBanda.setBounds(219, 84, 166, 20);
        panel2.add(tfNomeBanda);
        tfNomeBanda.setColumns(10);

        tfNroIntegrantes = new JTextField();
        tfNroIntegrantes.setColumns(10);
        tfNroIntegrantes.setBounds(219, 166, 128, 20);
        panel2.add(tfNroIntegrantes);

        JLabel lblCadastroDeBandas_1 = new JLabel("Cadastro de Bandas");
        lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setBounds(129, 25, 195, 30);
        panel2.add(lblCadastroDeBandas_1);

        JButton btnCadastrar = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        btnCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private String nomeB;
            private String paisB;
            private int nroIntegrantesB;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                nomeB = tfNomeBanda.getText();
                paisB = tfPaisBanda.getText();
                nroIntegrantesB = Integer.parseInt(tfNroIntegrantes.getText());

                //Objeto Banda
                bandas.add(new Banda(nomeB, paisB, nroIntegrantesB));

                taSaida.append(nomeB + "," + paisB + "," + nroIntegrantesB + "\n");
                //Acho que aqui termina assim


                //Aqui SALVAR TXT
                File arquivo = new File("Pasta/bandas.txt");

                try {
                    arquivo.createNewFile();

                    FileWriter escrever = new FileWriter(arquivo, false);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(escrever);


                    bw.write(taSaida.getText());

                    //Fechar
                    bw.close();
                    escrever.close();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Aqui mostra msg de Cadastro Efetuado
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banda Cadastrada com Sucesso!");
            }
        });
        btnCadastrar.setBounds(173, 211, 115, 23);
        panel2.add(btnCadastrar);

        JLabel lblNomeBanda = new JLabel("Nome Banda");
        lblNomeBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblNomeBanda.setBounds(90, 85, 109, 14);
        panel2.add(lblNomeBanda);

        JLabel lblPasBanda = new JLabel("Pa\u00EDs Banda");
        lblPasBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblPasBanda.setBounds(109, 124, 109, 14);
        panel2.add(lblPasBanda);

        JLabel lblNmerosIntegrantes = new JLabel("N\u00FAmeros Integrantes");
        lblNmerosIntegrantes.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblNmerosIntegrantes.setBounds(39, 167, 208, 19);
        panel2.add(lblNmerosIntegrantes);

        JButton btnCadastroMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
        btnCadastroMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Código Cadastro -> Menu
                panel2.setVisible(false);
                panel1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnCadastroMenuVoltar.setBounds(39, 211, 115, 23);
        panel2.add(btnCadastroMenuVoltar);

        JButton btnLimparCadastro = new JButton("Limpar");
        btnLimparCadastro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Código Limpar dados
                tfNomeBanda.setText("");
                tfPaisBanda.setText("");
                tfNroIntegrantes.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnLimparCadastro.setBounds(298, 211, 115, 23);
        panel2.add(btnLimparCadastro);

        panel3 = new JPanel();
        principal.add(panel3, "name_3607965415174");
        panel3.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Nome Banda Remover");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(44, 97, 173, 14);
        panel3.add(lblNewLabel);

        tfNomeBandaRemover = new JTextField();
        tfNomeBandaRemover.setBounds(211, 96, 197, 20);
        panel3.add(tfNomeBandaRemover);
        tfNomeBandaRemover.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblRemoverBanda = new JLabel("Remover Banda");
        lblRemoverBanda.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblRemoverBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblRemoverBanda.setBounds(131, 11, 195, 30);
        panel3.add(lblRemoverBanda);

        JButton btnRemoverMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
        btnRemoverMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Código Remover -> Menu
                panel3.setVisible(false);
                panel1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnRemoverMenuVoltar.setBounds(29, 202, 115, 23);
        panel3.add(btnRemoverMenuVoltar);

        JButton btnRemover = new JButton("Remover");
        btnRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                // LEITURA TXT

                try {

                    FileReader ler = new FileReader("Pasta/bandas.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ler);

                    String nomeB = null;
                    String[] x;

                    while ((nomeB = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        x = nomeB.split(",");

                        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                            String paisB = (x[1]);

                            int nroIntegrantesb = Integer.parseInt(x[2]);   

                            //Objeto
                            bandas.add(new Banda(nomeB, paisB, nroIntegrantesb));
                        }

                        taSaida.append(nomeB + "\n");

                    }

                    //fechar
                    br.close();
                    ler.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                String[] linha = bandas.get(0).getNome().split(",");
                System.out.println(linha[0]); // AQUI MOSTRA SÓ RUSH(nome banda) posicao ZERO

                //Código Remover Banda              
                for (int i = 0; i < bandas.size(); i++) {   

                    if (bandas.get(i).getNome().equals(tfNomeBandaRemover.getText())) {
                        bandas.remove(i);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banda Removida com Sucesso!");
                    }

                }  
            }
        });
        btnRemover.setBounds(169, 202, 115, 23);
        panel3.add(btnRemover);

        JButton btnLimparRemover = new JButton("Limpar");
        btnLimparRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //código LIMPAR
                tfNomeBandaRemover.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnLimparRemover.setBounds(294, 202, 115, 23);
        panel3.add(btnLimparRemover);

        panel4 = new JPanel();
        principal.add(panel4, "name_4277677604689");
        panel4.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblConsultarBandas = new JLabel("Consultar Bandas");
        lblConsultarBandas.setBounds(146, 5, 142, 20);
        lblConsultarBandas.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblConsultarBandas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        panel4.add(lblConsultarBandas);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(32, 29, 379, 179);
        panel4.add(scrollPane);

        taSaida = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(taSaida);

        JButton btnConsultaMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
        btnConsultaMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //código Consulta -> Menu
                panel4.setVisible(false);
                panel1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnConsultaMenuVoltar.setBounds(188, 219, 115, 23);
        panel4.add(btnConsultaMenuVoltar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse codigo nao e executavel, falta classe Banda.

Comment: Boa noite Articuno eu fiz ela, já posto junto aqui.

Comment: E  uma amostragem do quem no arquivo bandas.txt tambem, senao esse codigo nem compila.

Comment: Agora acho que ta completo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema principal do seu código não remover é que você apenas remove a banda da lista, mas nada faz nos dados do arquivo, que onde a consulta está buscando e populando o campo de texto. Porém há diversos problemas nesse código que podem atrapalhar até a correção desse método, mas apenas listarei para que você verifique e corrija.

- melhore a organização do seu código, tudo que precisa se repetir muitas vezes no código pode ser simplificado virando um método(caso seja um conjunto de ações) ou uma variável de escopo mais amplo, caso seja uma atribuição recorrente. Você lê um caminho de arquivo diversas vezes, sendo que se precisar alterar, vai ter que sair caçando no código inteiro. Crie uma variável com escopo de classe e coloque o caminho lá, depois apenas invoque essa variável quando precisar acessar a informação. Como é um dado que não precisa ser alterado durante execução, pode deixar como `final`. Exemplo:

```
private final String  FILE_PATH = "Pasta\bandas.txt";
```

- Quando você cadastra uma banda, está declarando variáveis como private, sendo que o escopo delas é somente dentro do *listener*, isso não é necessário já que você está usando-as como variável local, apenas inicie as variáveis dentro do método, não precisa sair colocando modificador em todo canto, apenas onde ele é realmente necessário.
- Outro problema aqui e que você salva o que é exibido no `JTextArea`, então qual a utilidade de criar uma classe chamada `Banda`? Há um problema de entendimento de conceitos da linguagem aqui, a classe `Banda` é completamente inútil nesse código da forma como foi feito, bastaria apenas ler o arquivo e remover a linha correspondente ao nome buscado. Sugiro que, antes de tudo, siga a orientação do tópico acima e organize o código, separando ações especificas em métodos como "cadastrar banda" e "salvar banda", e depois apenas utilize estas ações. Se o objetivo é sempre exibir o arquivo atualizado, primeiro grave nele e depois exiba seu conteúdo.
- No seu código você cria 3 paineis num bloco gigante de código, o que novamente remete a dica do meu primeiro tópico. Recomendo que separe os paineis, seu código está sendo feito como se fosse programação estruturada e perdendo a chance de aproveitar o melhor que java te proporciona para organizar melhor teu código. Antes de escrever código, é preciso entender o que se está fazendo, organizar as idéias para poder criar algo que seja, antes de tudo, legível e bem estruturado.

Tópicos que recomendo para leitura:

- [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/28595)
- [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/28595) (é c# mas as dicas aplicam-se aqui também)
- [O que é codificação elegante?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/28595)
- [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/28595)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Articuno, vou ler com calma cada um dos links que passou acima.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos consegui resolver o problema com a ajuda de um colega, pois estava fazendo a leitura e gravação do arquivo.txt nos lugares errados, segue abaixo o novo código caso alguém passe por uma dúvida semelhante.

```
public class Exercicio1 {

private JFrame frmBandas;
ArrayList<Banda> bandas = new ArrayList<Banda>();
private JTextField tfPaisBanda;
private JTextField tfNomeBanda;
private JPanel panel2;
private JPanel panel1;
private JTextField tfNroIntegrantes;
private JTextField tfNomeBandaRemover;
private JPanel panel3;
private JPanel panel4;
private JTextArea taSaida;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Exercicio1 window = new Exercicio1();
                window.frmBandas.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Exercicio1() {
    initialize();
}





/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    //LER TXT
    File arquivo = new File("Pasta/bandas.txt");

    try {
        arquivo.createNewFile();

        FileReader ler = new FileReader(arquivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ler);

        String linha = null;

        while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] x = linha.split(",");

            bandas.add(new Banda(x[0], x[1], Integer.parseInt(x[2])));
        }

        //FECHAR
        br.close();
        ler.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    frmBandas = new JFrame();
    frmBandas.setTitle("BANDAS");
    frmBandas.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 312);
    frmBandas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmBandas.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel principal = new JPanel();
    frmBandas.getContentPane().add(principal);
    principal.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    principal.add(panel1, "name_47122994121324");
    panel1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblCadastroDeBandas = new JLabel("MENU BANDAS");
    lblCadastroDeBandas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblCadastroDeBandas.setBounds(134, 27, 163, 22);
    panel1.add(lblCadastroDeBandas);

    JButton btnCadastrarBanda = new JButton("Cadastrar Banda");
    btnCadastrarBanda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //código MENU -> Cadastrar Banda

            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel2.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnCadastrarBanda.setBounds(138, 78, 137, 23);
    panel1.add(btnCadastrarBanda);

    JButton btnRemoverBanda = new JButton("Remover Banda");
    btnRemoverBanda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código MENU -> Remover Banda
            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnRemoverBanda.setBounds(138, 112, 137, 23);
    panel1.add(btnRemoverBanda);

    JButton btnConsultarBandas = new JButton("Consultar Bandas");
    btnConsultarBandas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código MENU -> Consultar Bandas
            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel4.setVisible(true);
            taSaida.setText("");  //ASSIM só exibe o arquivo TXT uma única vez

            for (int i = 0; i < bandas.size(); i++) {
                taSaida.append("Nome: " + bandas.get(i).getNome() + " País: "+bandas.get(i).getPais()+ 
                        " Nro Integrantes: "+bandas.get(i).getNroIntegrantes() + "\n");
            }
        }

    });
    btnConsultarBandas.setBounds(138, 146, 137, 23);
    panel1.add(btnConsultarBandas);

    JButton btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
    btnSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //SALVAR TXT
            File arquivo = new File("Pasta/bandas.txt");

            try {
                arquivo.createNewFile();

                FileWriter escrever = new FileWriter(arquivo, false);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(escrever);

                for (int i = 0; i < bandas.size(); i++) {
                    bw.write(bandas.get(i).getNome() + "," + bandas.get(i).getPais() + "," +
                            String.valueOf(bandas.get(i).getNroIntegrantes()) + "\n");
                }

                //FECHAR
                bw.close();
                escrever.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //SAIR
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnSair.setBounds(138, 180, 137, 23);
    panel1.add(btnSair);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    principal.add(panel2, "name_47123033318588");
    panel2.setLayout(null);

    tfPaisBanda = new JTextField();
    tfPaisBanda.setColumns(10);
    tfPaisBanda.setBounds(219, 123, 128, 20);
    panel2.add(tfPaisBanda);

    tfNomeBanda = new JTextField();
    tfNomeBanda.setBounds(219, 84, 166, 20);
    panel2.add(tfNomeBanda);
    tfNomeBanda.setColumns(10);

    tfNroIntegrantes = new JTextField();
    tfNroIntegrantes.setColumns(10);
    tfNroIntegrantes.setBounds(219, 166, 128, 20);
    panel2.add(tfNroIntegrantes);

    JLabel lblCadastroDeBandas_1 = new JLabel("Cadastro de Bandas");
    lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblCadastroDeBandas_1.setBounds(129, 25, 195, 30);
    panel2.add(lblCadastroDeBandas_1);

    JButton btnCadastrar = new JButton("Cadastrar");
    btnCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private String nomeB;
        private String paisB;
        private int nroIntegrantesB;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            nomeB = tfNomeBanda.getText();
            paisB = tfPaisBanda.getText();
            nroIntegrantesB = Integer.parseInt(tfNroIntegrantes.getText());

            //Objeto Banda
            bandas.add(new Banda(nomeB, paisB, nroIntegrantesB));


            //Aqui mostra msg de Cadastro Efetuado
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banda Cadastrada com Sucesso!");
        }
    });
    btnCadastrar.setBounds(173, 211, 115, 23);
    panel2.add(btnCadastrar);

    JLabel lblNomeBanda = new JLabel("Nome Banda");
    lblNomeBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblNomeBanda.setBounds(90, 85, 109, 14);
    panel2.add(lblNomeBanda);

    JLabel lblPasBanda = new JLabel("Pa\u00EDs Banda");
    lblPasBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblPasBanda.setBounds(109, 124, 109, 14);
    panel2.add(lblPasBanda);

    JLabel lblNmerosIntegrantes = new JLabel("N\u00FAmeros Integrantes");
    lblNmerosIntegrantes.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblNmerosIntegrantes.setBounds(39, 167, 208, 19);
    panel2.add(lblNmerosIntegrantes);

    JButton btnCadastroMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
    btnCadastroMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código Cadastro -> Menu
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            panel1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnCadastroMenuVoltar.setBounds(39, 211, 115, 23);
    panel2.add(btnCadastroMenuVoltar);

    JButton btnLimparCadastro = new JButton("Limpar");
    btnLimparCadastro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código Limpar dados
            tfNomeBanda.setText("");
            tfPaisBanda.setText("");
            tfNroIntegrantes.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnLimparCadastro.setBounds(298, 211, 115, 23);
    panel2.add(btnLimparCadastro);

    panel3 = new JPanel();
    principal.add(panel3, "name_3607965415174");
    panel3.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Nome Banda Remover");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(44, 97, 173, 14);
    panel3.add(lblNewLabel);

    tfNomeBandaRemover = new JTextField();
    tfNomeBandaRemover.setBounds(211, 96, 197, 20);
    panel3.add(tfNomeBandaRemover);
    tfNomeBandaRemover.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblRemoverBanda = new JLabel("Remover Banda");
    lblRemoverBanda.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblRemoverBanda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblRemoverBanda.setBounds(131, 11, 195, 30);
    panel3.add(lblRemoverBanda);

    JButton btnRemoverMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
    btnRemoverMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código Remover -> Menu
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            panel1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnRemoverMenuVoltar.setBounds(29, 202, 115, 23);
    panel3.add(btnRemoverMenuVoltar);

    JButton btnRemover = new JButton("Remover");
    btnRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Código Remover Banda
            for (int i = 0; i < bandas.size(); i++) {

                if (bandas.get(i).getNome().equals(tfNomeBandaRemover.getText())) {
                    bandas.remove(i);

                    //Aqui mostra msg de Remoção Efetuada
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banda Removida com Sucesso!");
                }
            }


        }
    });
    btnRemover.setBounds(169, 202, 115, 23);
    panel3.add(btnRemover);

    JButton btnLimparRemover = new JButton("Limpar");
    btnLimparRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //código LIMPAR
            tfNomeBandaRemover.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnLimparRemover.setBounds(294, 202, 115, 23);
    panel3.add(btnLimparRemover);

    panel4 = new JPanel();
    principal.add(panel4, "name_4277677604689");
    panel4.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblConsultarBandas = new JLabel("Consultar Bandas");
    lblConsultarBandas.setBounds(146, 5, 142, 20);
    lblConsultarBandas.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblConsultarBandas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    panel4.add(lblConsultarBandas);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(32, 29, 379, 179);
    panel4.add(scrollPane);

    taSaida = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(taSaida);

    JButton btnConsultaMenuVoltar = new JButton("Menu");
    btnConsultaMenuVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //código Consulta -> Menu
            panel4.setVisible(false);
            panel1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnConsultaMenuVoltar.setBounds(188, 219, 115, 23);
    panel4.add(btnConsultaMenuVoltar);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frmBandas.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Arquivo");
    menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

    JMenuItem mntmCadastrar = new JMenuItem("Cadastrar");
    mntmCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel2.setVisible(true);
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            panel4.setVisible(false);

        }
    });
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmCadastrar);

    JMenuItem mntmRemover = new JMenuItem("Remover");
    mntmRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(true);
            panel4.setVisible(false);

        }
    });
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmRemover);

    JMenuItem mntmConsultar = new JMenuItem("Consultar");
    mntmConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel1.setVisible(false);
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            panel4.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmConsultar);

    JMenuItem mntmMenu = new JMenuItem("Menu");
    mntmMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel1.setVisible(true); 
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            panel4.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmMenu);

    JMenuItem mntmSair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
    mntmSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //SALVAR TXT
            File arquivo = new File("Pasta/bandas.txt");

            try {
                arquivo.createNewFile();

                FileWriter escrever = new FileWriter(arquivo, false);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(escrever);

                for (int i = 0; i < bandas.size(); i++) {
                    bw.write(bandas.get(i).getNome() + "," + bandas.get(i).getPais() + "," +
                            String.valueOf(bandas.get(i).getNroIntegrantes()) + "\n");
                }

                //FECHAR
                bw.close();
                escrever.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //SAIR
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmSair);
 }
}
```