# Existe uma classe base comum que um record é derivado?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, record-types

Todos os objetos em C# derivam de `Object`. Mas alguns tipos derivam de outro tipo mais específico que pode ser derivado de `Object`, por exemplo os tipos criados com `struct` derivam de `ValueType`, e as tipos enumerados derivam de `Enum` que por sua vez derivam de `ValueType`, que deriva de `Object`.

Imagino que o `record struct` derive de `ValueType`. Mas ele deriva de um tipo mais específico? E o `record` deriva direto de `Object` ou de outro tipo?

Se não derivar de nada específico, de onde vem a implementação dos métodos, `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`, `Equals()`, `Deconstruct()` (que nem existe no `Object`), etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato, os métodos que são disponibilizados automaticamente quando cria um [`record`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/539114/101) possuem implementações específicas e precisam vir de algum lugar. Mas elas são tão específicas que só podem existir analisando o código. Não pode ser uma implementação padrão que é derivada.

Além disso uma implementação derivada tem algumas dificuldades de performance, especialmente em `record struct` que fará *boxing* em várias situações por causa de uma derivação.

Então C# optou por gerar esses métodos através do compilador. É como se você tivesse escrito o método na mão, não tem derivação. Portanto só derivam de `Object` e `ValueType` mesmo.

Esta "nova" forma de tipo da linguagem não faz nada de mais, a não ser implementar esses métodos, não tem tratamento diferenciado pela linguagem, não é uma forma especial de tipo, é só um jeito mais automatizado de criar tipos, que [é útil especialmente em certas ocasiões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481890/101).

Então é derivado de `Object` (que tem certos métodos) ou de `ValueType` (que tem implementações um pouco mais específicas desses métodos), mas não usa a implementação padrão que vem desses tipos, ele faz a implementação. Ele não chama o método base.

Por exemplo o ´GetHashCode()` usa um algoritmo que costuma ser adequado pegando todos os campos como identidade do objeto. Sem usar [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101), que é importante.

Bem, de certa forma usa reflexão, mas em tempo de compilação, [não a reflexão que as pessoas estão acostumadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101).

E obviamente ele atualiza os métodos se algum campo mudar.

Até mesmo o `PrintMembers()` que é protegido no `Object` é implementado pelo compilador.

E claro, ele só gera se voê não criar sua própria implementação de algum dos métodos que ele  costuma cuidar para você.

C# tem adotado muito essa filosofia de geração de código para reduzir o [*boilerplate*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10575/101). `record` é sobre isso, não sobre orientação a objeto, cada vez menos importante na linguagem (mas ainda muito).

Código gerado por um simples `record` com apenas um campo `X`:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(0)]
public class Teste : IEquatable<Teste> {
    public int X;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected virtual Type EqualityContract {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get {
            return typeof(Teste);
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override string ToString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("Teste");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder)) {
            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
        }
        stringBuilder.Append('}');
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder) {
        RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack();
        builder.Append("X = ");
        builder.Append(X.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public static bool operator !=(Teste left, Teste right) {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public static bool operator ==(Teste left, Teste right) {
        return (object)left == right || ((object)left != null && left.Equals(right));
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(X);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return Equals(obj as Teste);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual bool Equals(Teste other) {
        return (object)this == other || ((object)other != null && EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract && EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(X, other.X));
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual Teste <Clone>$() {
        return new Teste(this);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected Teste(Teste original) {
        X = original.X;
    }

    public Teste() {}
}

namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis {
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Embedded]
    internal sealed class EmbeddedAttribute : Attribute {}
}

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Embedded]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Event | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.ReturnValue | AttributeTargets.GenericParameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class NullableAttribute : Attribute {
        public readonly byte[] NullableFlags;

        public NullableAttribute(byte P_0) {
            byte[] array = new byte[1];
            array[0] = P_0;
            NullableFlags = array;
        }

        public NullableAttribute(byte[] P_0) {
            NullableFlags = P_0;
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Embedded]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Delegate, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class NullableContextAttribute : Attribute {
        public readonly byte Flag;

        public NullableContextAttribute(byte P_0) {
            Flag = P_0;
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Embedded]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Module, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class RefSafetyRulesAttribute : Attribute {
        public readonly int Version;

        public RefSafetyRulesAttribute(int P_0) {
            Version = P_0;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Record.cs).

Eu acho que podia ser melhor, por isso não cai de amores pelo `record`, ainda que ele seja útil em alguns casos.